# Error while executing python manage.py runserver

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to python.
I created this file using following command:

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\django-admin startproject mysite
```

After that successfully created a file in directory.But when i run **C:\Python35\Scripts\mysite\python manage.py migrate** or **C:\Python35\Scripts\mysite\python manage.py runserver**,
i am getting the following error

```
python is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be mixing up paths.

Generally, if you type `python`, the system looks up your `pythonpath`, and resolves it to the python executable.  On the windows systems I've used, that tends to be at c:\python35\python.exe

However, in this instance, you've given it a full path, but not actually pointed it to the executable.

I believe (assuming your path is correct) that this version should work:
`C:\Python35\Scripts\mysite\python.exe manage.py migrate`.

That said, on my windows machines, I can just do 
`manage.py migrate`, because the python.exe is set by pythonpath when Python3.5 was installed.

Tl;dr:

Run `manage.py migrate` or use a full path to the executable.